# Authoritative documentation on SIgnificant Location Updates

Tags: ios, geolocation

The following the Apple doc...

PDF:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/CoreLocation_Framework.pdf

or HTML:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW43

... includes this text about significant location updates:

"Note: Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes."

Are these not contradictory statements?

When I use Tom Horn's LocationTest http://www.cannonade.net/blog.php?id=1480 and the iPhone simulator's Debug>Location>Freeway Drive for Significant Updates only, it seems like it updates every 30 seconds.

Am I wrong? Is there any authoritative documentation of the algorithm? I understand it's based on cell towers or some other (non GPS) means.

Thanks, Jack